# How to verify that an application exists in Wildfly

Tags: wildfly

I am trying to automate the installation of a database driver in Wildfly and I have a CLI script that manages this. The problem is that if the application is enabled, I can not unload the database driver so today I have to manually disable it, before the upgrade.

In the CLI I can verify that the application is there by giving the `deployment list` command and I can also disable and enable from the CLI so in theory I can say `deployment disable my-app.ear`, do the upgrade, and then do `deployment enable my-app.ear`.

This works well as long as the application `my-app.ear` is deployed -- if I have an empty slate the CLI script will stop with an error message

```
{"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[(\"deplo
yment\" => \"my-app.ear\")]' not found"}}
```

How can I check for the existence of `my-app.ear` in my CLI script and thus only do disable when there is something to disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (outcome == success) of /deployment=my-app.ear:read-resource
  deployment disable my-app.ear
end-if
```

should do it

Comment: I have used the `if (outcome == success)...` before and guessed it might be applicable but was not able to understand how to apply it in this case. Thank you!